# _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() not outputting anything

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm writing a Vulkan API demo in C++ and it would be useful to have my program output any memory leaks to the output window. `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` doesn't output anything however.

The project is built in debug mode. Here's part of the code I have:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

at the start of `int main()`:

```
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
```

at the end:

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
return 0;
```

I create a few objects inbetween without deleting them so I know there are memory leaks.
`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` does return 1, but does not output anything.

`_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );` doesn't work either.

Comment: How are you creating the objects?

Comment: @RichardCritten just using the new operator. Seems like the problem has somehow fixed itself though, I added a line that just outputs a message in case _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() returns true and suddenly it actually outputs properly.

Comment: I'd assume that _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks are only track the leaks from malloc free in the linked crt but the ICD could use VirtualAlloc directly which then isn't tracked by CrtDumpMemoryLeaks.

Comment: @kiamvdd can you please share what did you add? facing similar problem here..